# Printing a matched regexp with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

So I'm trying to match a regexp with any string in the middle of it and then print out just that string.  The syntax is sort of like this...

```
sed -n 's/<title>.*</title>/"what do I put here"/p' input.file
```

and I just want to print out whatever .* is where I typed "what do I put here".  I'm not very comfortable with sed at this point so this is likely a very simple answer and I'm having trouble finding one in any of the other questions.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture the pattern you want to *extract* within `\(...\)`, and then you can refer to it as `\1` in the replacement string:

```
sed -n 's/<title>\(.*\)</title>/\1/p' input.file
```

You can have multiple `\(...\)` expressions, and refer to them with `\1`, `\2`, `\3`, and so on.

If you have the GNU version of `sed`, or `gsed`, then you could simplify a bit:

```
sed -rn 's/<title>(.*)</title>/\1/p' input.file
```

With the `-r` flag, `sed` can use "extended regular expressions", which practically let's you write `(...)` instead of `\(...\)`, `+` instead of `\+`, and other goodies.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the \(...\) syntax to go along with \1.